# how to know which button is clicked in other activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities, `Activity 1` and `Activity 2`.  `Activity 1` contains 8 buttons, each button sends some data to `Activity 2` through intents and `Activity 2`  takes data and shows in `listview`. I want to show data in listview based on the condition so in `Activity 2`  I put every button data in a `if` block

## So my problem is

What condition I should place in `if(condition?)` to know which button is clicked in `Activity 1` 
my `Activity 1`

```
public void hmoral(View v){
        moralref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    List<String> moraldata = new ArrayList<>();
                    Map<String,Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry:map.entrySet()){
                        moraldata.add(entry.getKey());
                        Log.d(TAG,entry.getKey());
                    }
                      Intent intent1 = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                      intent1.putExtra("moraldata", (Serializable) moraldata);
                      startActivity(intent1);

                }
                }
        });
    }


    public  void hhorror(View v){
        horrorref.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    List<String> horrordata = new ArrayList<>();
                    Map<String,Object> map = task.getResult().getData();
                    for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry:map.entrySet()){
                        horrordata.add(entry.getKey());
                        Log.d(TAG,entry.getKey());
                    }
                      Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                      intent.putExtra("horrordata", (Serializable) horrordata);
                      startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

code of `Activity2` below:

```
public class ListAcivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView originallist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_acivity);
        originallist = findViewById(R.id.originallist);


        if (){

          ArrayList<String> morallist = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("moraldata");
          ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,morallist);
          originallist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

         if (){
        ArrayList<String> horrorlist =  getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("horrordata");
        ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,horrorlist);
        originallist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
         }


    }
```

Comment: you have 8 button and all have different name right?

Comment: yes, I have 8 buttons with different name and id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to know which button is clicked in other activity

Send Button id using intent to next Activity :

```
intent.putExtra("clicked_view_id", view.getId());
```

Now use `clicked_view_id` with switch case to compare with Button ids:

```
int clickedButtonID = getIntent().getIntExtra("clicked_view_id", 0);
switch(clickedButtonID){
  case R.id.button1:
   ...
   break;
  case R.id.button2:
   ... 
   break;

}
```

Comment: why the default value is zero

Comment: @RahulSingh `getIntExtra` method takes two params first is key and second param is default value for case when if provided `key` is not found in Intent. you can use `default` in switch case to handle this condition

Comment: @RahulSingh: or you can use any default value like `R.id.button1` for case when key not found.

Comment: bother it work well  but it doesn't show any data in listview now

Comment: @RahulSingh: data is not visiable other issue. make a new question for this if still getting any other issue.

Answer (score 1):

In your activity1 :

```
    Private  String buttonText ="";

    yourButtonClick.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
 buttonText = getIntent().getStringExtra("btn_text");

    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            buttonText = "buttonOne";
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            buttonText = "buttonTwo";
            break;
        case R.id.button8:
            buttonText = "buttonEight";
            break;

       }

     }

  }
 Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("btnClicked", buttonText);
                   startActivity(intent);
```

// In list activity

```
 String btnClicked = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("btnClicked");
```